# JSON: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

In a rails app I have an object defined in a controller containing an icon and some values:

```
@data = "<i class='fa fa-circle fa-lg'></i><span>Speed: </span> #{b.speed.to_f} | Time: #{b.gps_date.try(:strftime, '%-m/%e %H:%M')}} <br />".html_safe.to_json
```

In view I parse it like this:

```
<script>
  var data = JSON.parse('<%= raw @data.as_json %>');
</script>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I works fine when I remove the icon code that contains the single quotes for class

```
<i class='fa fa-circle fa-lg'></i>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Not a solution but just curious to know, why are you using `to_json` and `as_json` ?

Comment: I get the same error if I don't use these methods. I'm actually using this object in JavaScript so tried `to_json` and then parsed the json in JS

Comment: This does not look like a object. I guess you are trying to build a html node and pass it to JS then I guess only `'<%= raw @data %>'` should work. Have you tried ?

Comment: You're right. Removed all json parsing code and used just raw @data. It worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: I will post this as answer, if you want then you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to send the HTML string to JS so need of `to_json`, as this is used to convert `Hash` to `JSON` . So just use `html_safe` in server side.

And in client side, since you have the all HTML in string no need of `as_json`, just use the string as you would normally do in JS. `as_json` is a method used as ActiveRecord Serializer.

```
@data = "<i class='fa fa-circle fa-lg'></i><span>Speed: </span> #{b.speed.to_f} | Time: #{b.gps_date.try(:strftime, '%-m/%e %H:%M')}} <br />".html_safe
```

and

```
var data = <%= raw @data %>;
```

Comment: Yes, I meant that. No need to parse as JSON since thats is a string. Forgot to remove while posting :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically this seems to be an issue with an unescaped `'` popping up somewhere in `JSON.parse('...')`. You can verify the issue by looking at the HTML of the rendered page.

I think you might fix your issue by declaring (no need for the `.to_json` here):

```
@data = "<i class='fa fa-circle fa-lg'></i><span>Speed: </span> #{b.speed.to_f} | Time: #{b.gps_date.try(:strftime, '%-m/%e %H:%M')}} <br />".html_safe
```

And then in the view use

```
var data = "<%= escape_javascript @data %>";
```

as you are only tring to pass a string there is no need for the conversion into a JSON object and then parsing it back. (You'd need that if you wanted to pass  a whole Javescript Object/Ruby Hash).

Actually for the last line there is also an equivalent shortcut/alias:

```
var data = "<%= j @data %>";
```

PS: I described how to fix the imminent issue but generally the point of MVC is to not have (or at least to minimize) presentation logic in a conroller. Generally it would be preferable to pass the data to the view and generate the HTML in the template.